# Drawings and practical implementation

Tags: search, epo, wipo, wo2009018016a2

In reference to the patent: [WO 2009/018016 A2](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2009018016A2)

In this patent there are no drawings and no any practical implementation is shown. How would I understand the practical concept?

Comment: please review the pdf sacn version of patent http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=WO&NR=2009018016A2&KC=A2&FT=D .. original document tab

Answer (score 1):

The WIPO Application can be downloaded from the [European Patent Register](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP08782191&tab=doclist). Select the "International publication of the A2 Pamphlet" entry and click on "Download Selected Documents". The application is 42 pages and the figures start on page 34.